# Processing data using pandas in a memory efficient manner using Python

Tags: python, pandas, memory

I have to read multiple csv files and group them by `"event_name"`. I also might have some duplicates, so I need to drop them. `paths` contains all the paths of the csv files, and my code is as follows:

```
data = []
for path in paths:
    csv_file = pd.read_csv(path)
    data.append(csv_file)

events = pd.concat(data)
events = events.drop_duplicates()

event_names = events.groupby('event_name')

ev2 = []

for name, group in event_names:
    a, b = group.shape
    ev2.append([name, a])
```

This code is going to tell me how many unique `event_name` unique there are, and how many entries per `event_name`. It works wonderfully, except that the csv files are too large and I am having memory problems. Is there a way to do the same using less memory?

I read about using `dir()` and `globals()` to delete variables, which I could certainly use, because once I have `event_names`, I don't need the DataFrame `events` any longer. However, I am still having those memory issues. My question more specifically is: can I read the csv files in a more memory-efficient way? or is there something additional I can do to reduce memory usage? I don't mind sacrificing performance, as long as I can read all csv files at once, instead of doing chunk by chunk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep a hash value of each row to reduce the data size.

```
csv_file = pd.read_csv(path)

# compute hash (gives an `uint64` value per row)
csv_file["hash"] = pd.util.hash_pandas_object(csv_file)

# keep only the 2 columns relevant to counting
data.append(csv_file[["event_name", "hash"]])
```

If you cannot risk hash collision (which would be astronomically unlikely), just use another hash key and check if the final counting results are identical. The way to change a hash key is as follows.

```
# compute hash using a different hash key
csv_file["hash2"] = pd.util.hash_pandas_object(csv_file, hash_key='stackoverflow')
```

Reference: [pandas official docs page](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.util.hash_pandas_object.html)